# How can I reload view in ExtJS4 via controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, view, controller, extjs4

I have a view. Controller is doing some logic, where I press some buttons in view (data passed to server and we have a callback).

I need to update (reload?) view via controller.

Comment: Do you mean a dataview (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.View)? Or just a panel with some fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know if I understand but, If you want to reload a grid after an insertion, you need to do this

> yourGrid.getView().refresh()

If you want to reload a store after an insertion, you need to do this:

> yourStore.load()

or through  grid

> yourGrid.getStore().load()

in your success or callback function in store.sync()

I hope I helped

Comment: +1 and this answer is almost two years old.  This brief answer had all the info I needed :)